# Breezejs BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate : Not able to access Navigation property

Tags: c#, angularjs, breeze

I am trying to access a navigation property in server side which is created newly in the client side.

Data Model.

```
public class Foo
{
        public string ID { get; set; } //Primary key
        public string Status { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
        public string ID { get; set; } //Foreign Key
        public string Notes { get; set; }     
}
```

On the client side:
I already have the parent object(id 123) and i am creating a new child object

```
function changeParentAndChild(foo){
foo.Status = 'Closed';
var barnotes = em.createEntity('Bar', { ID: 123});
barnotes.Notes = 'Sample text';
foo.Bars.push(barnotes);
}
```

After the saving the data using `manager.saveChanges();` On the server side

```
BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate += PerformPreSaveValidation()

public Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> PerformPreSaveValidation(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {

        foreach (Type entityType in saveMap.Keys)
        {
            if (entityType.Name == "Foo")
            {
                foreach (EntityInfo ei in saveMap[entityType])
                {
                    Foo objFoo = ((Foo)ei.Entity);
                    switch (objFoo.Status)
                    {
                        case "Closed":

                        //access parent id and status
                        string id = objFoo.ID;
                        string status = objFoo.Status

                        //access navigation property
                            string barnotes = objFoo.Bars.Last().Notes;
                            //invoke external method
                            Externalmethod(is,status,Notes)

                            break;                         
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }         


        return saveMap;
    }
```

When I am looping thru the savemap and try to access the navigation property. I am seeing it is empty. But the saveMap is having two entries, one parent Foo and one for the child Bars

The application uses:

```
Breezejs: Version: "1.4.7", metadataVersion: "1.0.5" 
EF6 
ASP.net 
web api 
Angular
```

Thanks,
Rajiv.

Answer (score 0):

breeze.contextprovider.nh now supports an override called BeforeSaveEntityGraph.
this is not yet published so you need to download from github.
EF version of this is not yet supported.
the problem is that the navigation properties are not yet "fixed" by the save process
and you have no way to do something after they do get fixed.